# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: php, javascript, html

tento pegar os valores de uma tabela e filtra-los, porem por algum motivo os valores resgatados estão em undefined e não tenho ideia de como resolver

```
<?php

include_once("conexao.php");

if (isset($_GET["id"])) {

    $id = $_GET["id"];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM acesso WHERE id = ?";

    $stmt = $conexao->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $id);
    $stmt->execute();

    if($obj = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
        $marca = $obj->marca;
        $modelo = $obj->modelo;
        $cor = $obj->cor;
    }

} else {
    $id=0;
    $marca="";
    $modelo="";
    $cor="";
}

?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>PHP</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #191919; color: white;">
    <div class="container">
        <form onsubmit="return validar();" action="bemvindo.php" method="POST" ">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Formulário</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="marca">Marca: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="marca" id="marca" placeholder="Exemplo: Toyota" value="<?=$marca?>" class="form-control"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="modelo">Modelo: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="modelo" id="modelo" placeholder="Exemplo: Golf 2016" value="<?=$modelo?>" class="form-control"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cor"">Cor: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="cor" id="cor" placeholder="Exemplo: Preto" value="<?=$cor?>" class="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <!-- Marca, Modelo, Cor -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$id?>"/>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Enviar</button>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <legend>Carros:</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="pesquisar" name="pesquisar" placeholder="Pesquisar" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
        <table class=" table table-dark" id="tabelaCarros">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Marca</th>
                    <th>Modelo</th>
                    <th>Cor</th>
                    <th>Editar</th>
                    <th>Excluir</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>        


                <?php

                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM acesso";

                    $stmt = $conexao->prepare($sql);
                    $stmt->execute();

                    while ($obj = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {

                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?=$obj->marca?></td>
                        <td><?=$obj->modelo?></td>
                        <td><?=$obj->cor?></td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="index.php?id=<?=$obj->id?>">
                                Editar
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="excluir.php?id=<?=$obj->id?>
                            "onclick="return confirm('Deseja realmente excluir?');">
                                Excluir
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php

                    }

                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    $("#pesquisar").keyup(function() {
        var pesquisar = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

        $("#tabelaCarros tbody tr").each(function() {

            data = $(this).data("pesquisar").toLowerCase();

            if(data.includes(pesquisar)) {
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        })
    });

    function validar(){
        if($("#marca").val() == ""){
            alert("Marca não preenchida. Preencha todos os campos.");
            return false;
        }
        if($("#modelo").val() == ""){
            alert("Modelo não preenchido. Preencha todos os campos.");
            return false;
        }
        if($("#cor").val() == ""){
            alert("Cor não preenchida. Preencha todos os campos.");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está verificando primeiro se o `$(this).data("pesquisar")` está retornando algum valor e não `undefined`? Na sua tabela não vejo e atributo "data-pesquisar" definido, vai dar erro.

Tentar usar o `toLowerCase()` em um valor `null` ou `undefined` dá erro, simulei seu erro abaixo:

```js
$("#pesquisar").keyup(function() {
   console.log('valor = "' + $(this).val() + '"');
   var pesquisar = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
   console.log(pesquisar);
   
   $("#tabelaCarros tbody tr").each(function() {
        var d = $(this).data("pesquisar");
  
        if (d == undefined)
           console.log("d=undefined, vai dar erro");
        else {
           data = $(this).data("pesquisar").toLowerCase();
           console.log("data=" + data);
        }
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
<input type="text" id="pesquisar"/>
</p>
<table class=" table table-dark" id="tabelaCarros">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Marca</th>
                    <th>Modelo</th>
                    <th>Cor</th>
                    <th>Editar</th>
                    <th>Excluir</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>        
                    <tr>
                        <td>Marca 1</td>
                        <td>Modelo X></td>
                        <td>Branco</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="index.php?id=<?=$obj->id?>">
                                Editar
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="excluir.php?id=<?=$obj->id?>
                            "onclick="return confirm('Deseja realmente excluir?');">
                                Excluir
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr data-pesquisar="sim">
                        <td>Marca 1</td>
                        <td>Modelo X></td>
                        <td>Branco</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="index.php?id=<?=$obj->id?>">
                                Editar
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="excluir.php?id=<?=$obj->id?>
                            "onclick="return confirm('Deseja realmente excluir?');">
                                Excluir
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Veja que na segunda `tr` acrescentei o atributo "data-pesquisar" e não dá erro.

Comment: ok, entendi oque você quis dizer e sim o erro não acontece mais mas mesmo assim agora ele só da undefined, eu devo ter errado algo no código mas como sou meio noob nisso ainda, não estou vendo onde errei, ou tentando ler os valores do banco de forma errada e ele esta pegando valores undefined, pois no outro código que fiz q busca do banco ele funciona perfeitamente, então deve ser eu fazendo besteira msm, só q não sei como prosseguir daqui pois não sei pq ele esta pegando valores undefined, era pra esses valores serem apenas tuplas do banco

Comment: Vamos por partes... primeiro, acho estranho esse código: `var d = $(this).data("pesquisar");`. Isso vai pegar um atributo "data-pesquisar" que não está definido no seu código, você deveria ter algo como `<tr data-pesquisar=<?=$obj->algumacoisa?>>`, mas fora isso precisa entender o que você quer pesquisar. Isso iria pesquisar alguma coisa na linha toda, é isso mesmo? Ou você quer pesquisar nas colunas de cada linha (marca, modelo e cor) por exemplo?

Comment: bem depois de vc mostrar meu erro, pensei em outra forma para fazer e funcionou, vlw